# Enable YouTube API on existing player

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have an embeded youtube video which I want the YouTube API applied. I add the url parameter using jQuery as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVEY9/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var obj = $('object');
 obj.find('embed').attr('src', function(i,s){return s+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'})
 obj.find('param[name=movie]').attr('value', function(i,v){return v+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'})

 $('.play').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].playVideo();
 });
 $('.pause').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();
 })
});
```

This method works great in Firefox, but not at all in IE or Chrome (not sure about other browsers). So my question is how do I modify this to make the API work in other browsers? Would I have to completely remove the object and replace it using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)?

Note: The embed code is directly from YouTube.

---

Update: I figured out if I remove the object, add the url parameters then add the object back, I can now get it to work in Chrome, but still not IE ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVEY9/2/)).

---

Addendum: Why doesn't the YouTube API function when the object/embed already has the enable code within it? I'm trying to avoid making SWFObject a dependancy.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="640" height="385">
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2Qj8PhxSnhg&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&enablejsapi=1&version=3"></param>
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
 <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2Qj8PhxSnhg&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&enablejsapi=1&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that Chrome and IE doesn't update the DOM/embed api for the element when you change it's src attribute. The code does work if you add the querystrings directly in the code. Does your site require it to be added dynamically?

Comment: @Manticore: It's not a requirement, I am trying to modify a plugin. The video code/link is added by the user in a list, so I was trying to determine the easiest way to make this work without setting any rules like no embed tags.

Comment: I had this same problem, and IE started behaving appropriately for me after adding the classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" attribute that SWFObject adds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding swfobject - yes. IE treats flash embeds slightly differently (thanks activex) than all the other browsers. check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie-automatic-component-activation-changes-to-ie-activex-update) to get an idea of why, and the [SWFObject documentation](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) for more information.

Also, I recently created a jQuery plugin to help control the embedded player using the player API (basically what you're doing).

Check it out, it's the jQuery TubePlayer plugin - http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin

Comment: So it looks like you are depending on the SWFObject plugin. I'm trying to find the essence of the problem. Digging through the SWFObject code to find the differences between browsers hasn't been very revealing to me.

Comment: I gave up and just went with using the SWFObject plugin, so I'm going to mark your answer as accepted even though I still couldn't find the essence of the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

IE isn't finding `$('object')` maybe because you need to specify the right type ( do an alert on the obj length ), but if you do `obj = $('embed')` it'll work. It might be wise to wrap things around in a different way, that is do `$('<div id="test/>')` and then append the embed/objects and change the `src` and `movie` values.

EDIT: IE doesn't seem to register `object` until it has a `type` or `clsid` attribute specified, eg

EDIT #2: You can probably just inspect the outerHTML of the object element @ http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/retrieve_cache?unique_id=http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/samples/boilerplateHTML/youtube/chromeless.html|http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/samples/js/youtube/chromeless.js&defaultSample=true

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem with IE not finding `$('object')` even without a CSID, at least in IE8. I did try adding the raw HTML using `outerHTML` as the SWFObject file does, but it didn't seem to make any difference.