# Enable Youtube's JS API after the movie was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking to control videos on my page, some of which may have not been embedded with the JavaScript API parameter on (enablejsapi) at first. They may come in both iframe or the old object embed types, though this shouldn't matter.

I looked around and none seem to be up to my standards, [Enable YouTube API on existing player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372574/enable-youtube-api-on-existing-player) - his answer restarts the player (re-creates the element with apienabled)

I'm having a hard time with the documentation here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference  both seem to focus on irrelevant stuff. No technical details on how the API actually treats the elements so it's hard for me to guess where to go with this. Not the first time Google's JavaScript API is giving me hard time, certainly not the last

So I want to be able to control, or at least partially control (listen to play/stop events) players currently on the page which when were first embedded, did not request the API with them. Is there a way to enable the JavaScript API for them live? or hack the way to it?

Update: My progress so far surrounds re-creating the elements on the page with the API, the one technique I was trying so hard to avoid. I'm still facing all sorts of object/iframe api differences that's making me want to change my career so it will take a bit more polish. I will paste some coffee code when I figure everything out. It's nothing too fancy, but it's the only universal way to add a 'global listener', if you will, to a page full of existing embedded videos not necessarily with API enabled in them.

**TLDR (Too Long Didn't Read)**: The Youtube API is imperfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the update, this question was solved by recreating the embed/iframe element. There isn't much magic here - just add the api variable to the URLs. Unfortunately I could not find a nicer way to enable it.